# How can i handle unmapped actions in struts 2 to redirect to some suitable error page?

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, struts

I am looking for a solution where i do not have action url in struts.xml but still if i access that url, So instead of giving struts error log, i want to redirect it to any custom and suitable error page.

Answer (score 0):

**Global Exception Handling**

If you want to show a error page for all errors, use the global exception handling, explained [here](http://struts.apache.org/getting-started/exception-handling.html).

The default is to use something like this:

```xml
<global-results>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</global-results>

<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error" />
</global-exception-mappings>
```

**Wildcard Mappings**

Or if you want to handle just unkown action names you could use the wildcard mapping explained [here](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/wildcard-mappings.html).

A solution could be:

```xml
<action name="/*" class="org.apache.struts.webapp.example.ErrorAction">
    <result>error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Make sure you put the wildcard actions on the top of the struts configuration, because the "last one wins".